# select2 how to display data

Tags: symfony, jquery-select2

I want to use select2 in my Symfony project but still do not know how to display results. My code for frontend is

```
    $(".js_search").select2({
                ajax: {
                    url: "{{ path('search') }}",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    delay: 250,
                    data: function (params) {
                        return {
                            q: params.term, // search term
                            page: params.page
                        };
                    },
                    processResults: function (data, params) {
                        console.log(data.items);
                        params.page = params.page || 1;

                        return {
                            results: data.items,
                            pagination: {
                                more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
                            }
                        };
                    },
                    cache: true
                },
                escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
                    return markup;
                }, // let our custom formatter work
                minimumInputLength: 1,
                templateResult: formatRepo, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
                templateSelection: formatRepoSelection // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
            });
        });
        function formatRepo (repo) {
            if (repo.loading) return repo.text;

            var markup = '<div class="clearfix">' +
                    '<div class="col-sm-1">' +
                    '<img src="' + repo.owner.avatar_url + '" style="max-width: 100%" />' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div clas="col-sm-10">' +
                    '<div class="clearfix">' +
                    '<div class="col-sm-6">' + repo.full_name + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-code-fork"></i> ' + repo.forks_count + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="col-sm-2"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> ' + repo.stargazers_count + '</div>' +
                    '</div>';

            if (repo.description) {
                markup += '<div>' + repo.description + '</div>';
            }
            markup += '</div></div>';
            return markup;
        }

        function formatRepoSelection (repo) {
            return repo.full_name || repo.text;
        }
```

g
and for the backend

```
    public function searchAction()
{
    $response = new Response();
    $response->setContent(json_encode(
        [
            'items' =>
                [
                    'id' => 1,
                    'text' => 'test'
                ]
        ]
    ));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $response;
}
```

I dont know how should $response looks like or how to show returned data in view.
Somebody know the answer ?

I am using this https://select2.github.io/

Comment: you could try the `JsonResponse` class. Maybe ti will fix things: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#creating-a-json-response If this won't "magically" fix your problems, invest further with the developer console of your browser of choice. Oftentimes it will open when you press F12

Comment: what error do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Your response should be a JSON array with the elements Select2 uses to create the option tags for the dropdown.

In your case the content in the reposnse to your AJAX request would be:

```
[{"id": 1, "text":"test"}]
```

Select2 will then update the element identifed by the JQuery Selector $(.js-search) with the options and values in your response.

Comment: I tried both using

    [{"id": 1, "text":"test"}]
and using jsonResponse but when I am writing f.e one letter a it gives me back no results found?